# Keycloak takes a long time to wake up if unused during a day or more

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I installed Keycloak with a docker compose, behind an NGINX reverse proxy. Keycloack is only installed now for testing.

When I stop using it for a days or more, next time I have a "Request Time-out" error, I need to refresh the page two times before it succeeds. Debug logs does not help me, the same one appears every 5 seconds:

```
keycloak    | 21:55:07,896 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) new JtaTransactionWrapper
keycloak    | 21:55:07,897 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) was existing? false
keycloak    | 21:55:07,897 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) JtaTransactionWrapper  commit
keycloak    | 21:55:07,897 DEBUG [org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper] (Timer-2) JtaTransactionWrapper end
keycloak    | 21:55:07,897 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner] (Timer-2) Executed scheduled task AbstractLastSessionRefreshStoreFactory$$Lambda$1335/0x0000000841587c
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Here my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: "mariadb:10.5"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /app/keycloak/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak_db
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ***
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "--silent"]
  keycloak: 
    image: "quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.1"
    environment:
        PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
        DB_VENDOR: MARIADB
        DB_ADDR: mariadb
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak_db
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_PASSWORD: ***
        KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
        # ROOT_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    container_name: keycloak
```